# Нежелательное преобразование массива JSON при удалении из него элемента функцией unset()

Tags: php, массивы, json

Заносим данные в JSON

```
$file = file_get_contents('./data.json');
$formdata = json_decode($file,TRUE);
unset($file);
$formdata []= array(
    'title' => $title,
    'data' => $data,
    'author' => $author,
    'message' => $message
);
file_put_contents('./data.json',json_encode($formdata));
unset($formdata);
```

Получаем массив:

```
[{"title":"1","data":"1","author":"1","message":"1"},{"title":"12","data":"12","author":"12","message":"12"},{"title":"123","data":"123","author":"123","message":"123"}]
```

При удалении одного объекта:

```
$filedata = json_decode(file_get_contents('./data.json'), true);
$index = array_count_values([$_POST['index']]);
$array_number = key($index);
unset($filedata[$array_number]); 
file_put_contents('./data.json', json_encode($filedata));
```

кроме удаления, происходит "преобразование" массива в

```
{"0":{"title":"1","data":"1","author":"1","message":"1"},"2":{"title":"123","data":"123","author":"123","message":"123"}}
```

и после этого я не могу больше добавлять элементы в него (удаление идет нормально).

Как сделать чтобы при удалении элементов массива он не менял вид, а просто удалялся один элемент массива? Пример (так нужно чтобы выглядел массив после удаление [1]-го элемента):

```
[{"title":"1","data":"1","author":"1","message":"1"},{"title":"123","data":"123","author":"123","message":"123"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file_put_contents('./data.json',json_encode(array_values($formdata)));
```

У вас были ключи 0, 1 и 2 в PHP-массиве после распаковки `json_decode`. После удаления элемента стали ключи 0 и 2. `json_encode` не знает, нужны ли вам ключи в дальнейшем и пытается их сохранить - но у массива в `JSON` нельзя задать ключи, поэтому `json_encode` решает писать объект, а не массив. Вызовом `array_values` можно создать копию PHP-массива с простыми числовыми последовательными ключами и такой массив без проблем запишется как `JSON`-массив.

Answer (score 2):

Можно удалять при помощи `array_splice()`. Эта функция перенумеровывает индексы, поэтому у вас в JSON останется массив.

То есть вместо:

```
unset($filedata[$array_number]);
```

нужно написать:

```
array_splice($filedata, $array_number, 1);
```

Если необходимо удалять несколько элементов, то при удалении могут возникнуть проблемы (поскольку индекс следующего удаляемого элемента может поменяться). В этом случае вы можете удалять функцией `unset()`, а потом взять массив при помощи функции `array_values()`